# Use specific subnet id in load balancer module Terraform using Azure as cloud provider

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I try to deploy a Terraform infrastructure which contains a Vnet, four subnets and two load balancers.The values for subnets are stored in a variable with type map(any). When I create the load balancer, I want to specify that the internal load balancer should be assoiciated with "subnet_ha".

main.tf

```
module "vnet" {
  source             = "/home/user/personal/tf-modules/azure/az-vnet"
  vnet_name          = "glb-net-p-${local.location}-sdwan-vnet"
  location           = local.location
  rg_name            = local.rg_name
  vnet_address_space = var.vnet_address_space
  dns_servers        = var.dns_servers
  tags = {
    Name        = "glb-net-p-euwe-sdwan-vnet"
    Environment = "Test"
    Creator     = "tf"
  }
  depends_on = [
    module.resource_group
  ]
}

module "subnet" {
  source            = "/home/user/personal/tf-modules/azure/az-subnet"
  for_each          = var.subnets
  rg_name           = local.rg_name
  subnet_name       = each.key
  address_prefixes  = each.value.address_prefixes
  virtual_vnet_name = module.vnet.vnet_name
  depends_on = [
    module.vnet
  ]
}

module "load_balancer" {
  source                        = "/home/bdaniel/personal/tf-modules/azure/az-load-balancer"
  for_each                      = local.load_balancers
  name                          = each.key
  rg_name                       = local.rg_name
  location                      = local.location
  name_frontend_ip_config       = each.value.name_frontend_ip_config
  public_ip_address_id          = each.value.public_ip_address_id
  subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet_id
  private_ip_address            = each.value.private_ip_address
  private_ip_address_allocation = each.value.private_ip_address_allocation
  lb_pool                       = each.value.lb_pool
  name_lb_probe                 = each.value.name_lb_probe
  port_probe                    = each.value.port_probe
  interval_in_seconds           = each.value.interval_in_seconds
  number_of_probes              = each.value.number_of_probes
  protocol                      = each.value.protocol
  sku                           = each.value.sku
  depends_on = [
    module.subnet
  ]
}
```

values.tfvars

```
subnets = {
  subnet_public = {
    address_prefixes = ["172.26.40.0/28"]
  }
  subnet_private = {
    address_prefixes = ["172.26.40.16/28"]
  }
  subnet_ha = {
    address_prefixes = ["172.26.40.32/28"]
  }
  subnet_mgt = {
    address_prefixes = ["172.26.40.48/28"]
  }
}
```

locals.tf

```
locals {
  rg_name        = "euwe-sdwan-rg"
  location       = "germanywestcentral"
  project        = "sdwan"
  subnet_ids     = [for s in module.subnet : s.subnet_id]
  public_ips     = [for p in module.public_ip : p.public_ip_id]
  lb_ids         = [for l in module.load_balancer : l.lb_id]
  lb_probe_ids   = [for a in module.load_balancer : a.lb_probe_id]
  lb_backend_ids = [for b in module.load_balancer : b.lb_backend_id]


  load_balancers = {
    external_lb = {
      name_frontend_ip_config       = "sdwan-ELB"
      subnet_id                     = ""
      public_ip_address_id          = module.public_ip[0].public_ip_id
      private_ip_address            = ""
      private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
      lb_pool                       = "sdwan-ELB-Backend-pool"
      name_lb_probe                 = "sdwan-ELB-Backend-probe"
      port_probe                    = 8008
      interval_in_seconds           = 5
      number_of_probes              = 2
      protocol                      = "Tcp"
      sku                           = "Standard"
    }
    internal_lb = {
      name_frontend_ip_config       = "sdwan-ILB"
      subnet_id                     = local.subnet_ids[0]
      public_ip_address_id          = ""
      private_ip_address            = "172.26.40.38"
      private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
      lb_pool                       = "sdwan-ILB-Backend-pool"
      name_lb_probe                 = "sdwan-ILB-Backend-probe"
      port_probe                    = 8008
      interval_in_seconds           = 5
      number_of_probes              = 2
      protocol                      = "Tcp"
      sku                           = "Standard"
    }
  }
```

subnet-module.tf

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "sdwan" {
  name                 = var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.rg_name
  virtual_network_name = var.virtual_vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = var.address_prefixes
}
```

output-subnet-module.tf

```
output "subnet_id" {
    value = azurerm_subnet.sdwan.id
}
```

Currently I created in locals.tf a variable called "subnet_ids" in which I use a for to get all subnets ids and use them in other modules using they're position.

locals.tf

```
subnet_ids     = [for s in module.subnet : s.subnet_id]

internal_lb = {
      name_frontend_ip_config       = "sdwan-ILB"
      subnet_id                     = local.subnet_ids[0]
      public_ip_address_id          = ""
      private_ip_address            = "172.26.40.38"
      private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
      lb_pool                       = "sdwan-ILB-Backend-pool"
      name_lb_probe                 = "sdwan-ILB-Backend-probe"
      port_probe                    = 8008
      interval_in_seconds           = 5
      number_of_probes              = 2
      protocol                      = "Tcp"
      sku                           = "Standard"
    }
```

What I tried was to add a if statement in for and verify that the "subnet_ha" key is present and stored. But the problem here is that the value in "subnet_ids" will be a tuple and can't be used as a string("tostring" can't convert a tuple to a string).
I also tried to iterate through "subnets" variable which contains the value.

locals.tf

```
subnet_ha_id   = [for sh in keys(var.subnets) : sh.subnet_id if sh =="subnet_ha"]
```

But in this case I get the following error

```
Unsupported attribute
│
│   on locals.tf line 10, in locals:
│   10:   subnet_ha_id   = [for sh in keys(var.subnets) : sh.subnet_id if sh =="subnet_ha"]
│
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
```

Currently for "subnet_id" in "internal_lb" I access each id by their position, but I can't be sure that in a next apply, "subnet_ha" will be in the same position
What I want is to store the value in a variable and used it later in other modules.
The Terraform version I use is 1.3.9 and AzureRM provider is 3.45.0

Answer (score 0):

***I have tried with following code and it worked for me:***

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
  name                = "PublicIPForLB"
  location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}
# Define the Vnet
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "my_vnet" {
  name                = "mykavnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

# Define the subnets


resource "azurerm_subnet" "my_subnets" {
  count               = length(keys(var.subnet_map))
  name                = keys(var.subnet_map)[count.index]
  address_prefixes    = [values(var.subnet_map)[count.index]]
  virtual_network_name= azurerm_virtual_network.my_vnet.name
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}


resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "TestLoadBalancer"
  location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip.id
  }
}
```

**I have used locals  where subnet is queried for the name `subnet_ha`**

```
 locals {
    subnet_ha_index = index([for subnet in azurerm_subnet.my_subnets : subnet.name], "subnet_ha")
  }
```

***`Subnet_ha` is associated to internal load balancer using the `index` as following:***

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "internal_lb" {
  name                = "internal-lb"
  location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal-ip"
    //subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.my_subnets[3].id # This is the index of the "subnet_ha" subnet in the list of subnets
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.my_subnets[local.subnet_ha_index].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address            = "10.0.4.10"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Reference :** https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/lb